# Email validation doesn't capture with required fileds

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript validation function.I need to check if required fileds are empty or wrong mail address.Required fileds empty is working But when i type mail like abc@abc or something wrong then it doent catch the error in my code.

> > When i type all required fileds but wrong email address ( abc@abc or abc.com like doesn't capture.)

My Code

```
 function newsValidation() {

    var status = true;
    if (($.trim($('#txtNewsname').val()) == '') || ($.trim($('#txtnewsarea').val()) == '') ||
        ($.trim($('#txtemail').val()) == '')) {

        $("#reqfield").removeClass("hidden");

        if (!ValidateEmail($("#txtemail").val())) {
            $("#emailval").removeClass("hidden");
        }
        status = false;
    }
```

Email Validate Function

```
 function ValidateEmail(email) {
    var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    return expr.test(email);
}
```

Comment: Maybe try using regex from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test for a valid email is inside the `if` block which test if the value is not `null`, so when you enter any value in the text box (whether its valid or not) the `if (!ValidateEmail($("#txtemail").val())) {` will never be called. Change your script to

```
function newsValidation() {
  var status = true;
  if (($.trim($('#txtNewsname').val()) == '') || ($.trim($('#txtnewsarea').val()) == '') || ($.trim($('#txtemail').val()) == '')) {
    $("#reqfield").removeClass("hidden");
    status = false;
  } else if (!ValidateEmail($("#txtemail").val())) {
    $("#emailval").removeClass("hidden");
    status = false;
  }
}
```

Side note: All this functionality is provide out of the box in MVC by simply adding the `[Required]` and `[EmailAddress]` attribute to your property and including the relevant scripts (`jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`) and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` helpers which means you get both client and server side validation (and it's all done correctly!)